# How to create a stacked bar plot for a dataframe containing individual open/close states?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a stacked bar plot where the state is on the x-axis and each state's bar show opened and closed proportion. I have data something like this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# it's dataframe
state  complaints_status
 a         closed
 b         closed
 c         open
 a         closed
 a         open
 e         open
```

I tried to solve it but It doesn't work

```py
states = list(complaints_df.State.unique())
closed = []
opened = []
def status(state):
    if 'Closed' in complaints_df[complaints_df['State'] == state]['Complaints_status'].value_counts():
        closed.append(complaints_df[complaints_df['State'] == state]['Complaints_status'].value_counts()['Closed'])
    if 'Open' in complaints_df[complaints_df['State'] == state]['Complaints_status'].value_counts():
        opened.append(complaints_df[complaints_df['State'] == state]['Complaints_status'].value_counts()['Open'])
for state in states:
    status(state)

# plotting stack bar chart
indx = list(range(len(states)))
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
graph_state = plt.bar(x=indx, height=states, width=0.35)
graph_closed = plt.bar(x=indx, height=closed, width=0.35, bottom=states)
graph_opened = plt.bar(x=indx, height=opened, widht = 0.35, bottom=closed+states)
plt.xlabel('States')
plt.ylabel('Complaints')
plt.show()
```

I realize that, this is wrong as it not depicts precisely that which state has open and closed complaints so  how should I solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work. I first created some random data for testing.

Then:

- groupby(['state', 'complaints_status']).size():

  - groups per state and per status and counts by taking the size
- ... .unstack():

  - to convert the two rows for each state into one row with separate columns for opened and closed
- ... .fillna(0):

  - when some state has zero opened or closed complaints, .size gave `Not a Number`, replace those with zeros
- ... .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

  - create the plot

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

states = ['Maryland','Georgia','Michigan','California','NewMexico','Indiana','Virginia','Illinois','Pennsylvania','Massachusetts','Oregon','Texas','NewHampshire','Minnesota','Tennessee','Colorado','Florida','Alabama','Washington','NewYork','NewJersey','Maine','Missouri','WestVirginia','Montana','Mississippi','Connecticut','Vermont','Kentucky','SouthCarolina','Ohio','Utah','Delaware','Arkansas','Nevada','Louisiana','Kansas','Arizona','North Carolina','Rhode Island','District of Columbia','Iowa']
status_options = ["open", "closed"]
num_states = len(states)

N = 300
# create a random list of states (with repitition)
complaints_states = np.random.choice(states, N)
# generate random status, with a little higher probability for "closed"
complaints_status = np.random.choice(status_options, N, p=[0.3, 0.7])
# create a dataframe
complaints_df = pd.DataFrame({'state': complaints_states, 'complaints_status': complaints_status})

# create the plot
complaints_df.groupby(['state', 'complaints_status']).size().unstack().fillna(0).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.xlabel('')  # remove unnecessary 'state' label
plt.ylabel('Number of Complaints')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: generated plot]

Comment: I don't understand why you took 300 **random** states and status and after doing this will graph represent the true data

Comment: what is the use of unstack()

Comment: I took random state/status combinations because I don't have access to your true data and needed data to experiment and create an example plot. Just remove all the code from `N=300` until and including `complaints_df=...`. And replace it with creating or reading your own dataframe. Just make sure you use the same names for the columns, or change the code accordingly.

Comment: @DarkstarDream Without `unstack()`, the groupby dataframe has a two rows per state. `unstack()` replaces `Alabama, closed, 7`, `Alabama, open, 3` with `Alabama, closed, 7, open, 3`

Comment: By the way, do unstack works in converting multi-indexed data into a simple data frame. Actually I am wondering how to convert multi-indexed data into data frame too

Comment: @DarkstarDream Probably, yes.  Just create a small dataframe with enough data for experimenting. Try different options, print the resulting dataframe and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205995/discussion-between-darkstar-dream-and-johanc).